# AnyLogic - custom network

Tags: anylogic

I'm still having troubles with AnyLogic...I'm developing an epidemic SIRS model and I want to define my own network.

In particular, I have this matrix that defines the daily average number of contacts between age class
[image]

and therefore I want every agent to establish contact with other agents according to this matrix...it is driving me crazy :S

AgeClass is a parameter calculated with the following function
[image]

I thought to setup an event that occurs once at the beginning with the following code 
[image]

Now I am saying "connect n times to a random agent"...what I want to say is "connect n times to a random agent **with AgeClass k**" is there a way to do so?

thanks for the support!

ps when I write `int i = AgeClass` i takes the value of the parameter AgeClass of the agent that is running the code, right? So i it will be different for different agents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you have already found a solution. Here a way to do it:

1. Regarding age, you don't need that big *if/else if* sequence. Just do something like this:

`int ageClass = 0; // a variable of agents
    ageClass = (int) floor(age / 5.0);
    if (age >= 70.0 ) ageClass == 14; // just to be sure that max class is 14
    return ageClass;`

2. Regarding the network. I would create a function named `setup`, so that you can put it in agent actions, on startup, e.g. `setup();`
3. You can create a *link to agents* object at the agent level (`Person` in my code, I use a connection object named *contacts*). The function would be something like:

`// loop through age groups
    for (int i = 0; i  < network[0].length; i++) { 
       ArrayList<Person> ageGroupPeople = new ArrayList<Person>();
       for (Person p : population ) {
         if ( p.ageClass == i ) { ageGroupPeople.add(p) }  \\ create pool of potential alters by age
       }
      \\ create network per agent
      for (Person ego : population ) {
         for (int k = 0; k < poisson(network[ego.ageClass][i]); k++) { 
             Person alter = randomFrom(ageGroupPeople);
             if ( ego != alter ) { ego.contacts.connectTo(alter);}
       }
    }`

I haven't checked the code and how slow might be, it is just one way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

In AnyLogic, you can represent a matrix as two-dimensional Java array:
http://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.xj.anylogic.help/html/code/Arrays.html

After initializing the matrix, you may define custom contact network using the element 'Link to agents':
http://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.xj.anylogic.help/html/agentbased/Link.html

Comment: Thanks @TatianaGomzina ! I managed to define the matrix...yet I'm having trouble with defining the network :(